# hibernate Custom Multiple Fields Selection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

We have several models like below.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    public String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long ssid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public int age;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public long registration;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Car> cars;


}
```

Car model

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false,  unique = true)
    public String plateNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Person person;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Fabric fabric;

}
```

Fabric model

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Fabric {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;


    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    public String name;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fabric")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Car> cars;
}
```

The problem is, We use only *some* attributes of the model on different modules. It is ok with when we call simple typed attributes, but when querying something like this;

```
session.createQuery("select name, cars from Person order by registration desc ");
```

we get errors. Can anyone help?

```
   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:370)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1481)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1441)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
    org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.getAllPostOverview(Unknown Source)
    jarvis.api.story.PostController.getAllPostOverviews(PostController.java:51)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace so we see the root cause?

Comment: Also add the Car entity code

Comment: @MaciejKowalski i have upload models

Comment: What about the full stracktrace of the erro, @raigeki?

Comment: @Naros i have uploaded stacktrace

Comment: Thanks, one last question, which hibernate-core version?

Comment: @Naros 5.2.6.Final.

Comment: @Naros Do you know tutorial or samples with related this type custom selection?

Comment: @Naros: In this moment I've no an environment with 5.2.6 so in doubt I've deleted my answer ;)

Comment: @JoeTaras can we call this type of selection, with other hibernate versions?

Comment: The `SELECT NEW` and JPA `CriteriaBuilder#construct` concepts were introduced in JPA 2.0, so any Hibernate version that is JPA 2.0 is compliant should support that syntax.  The only caveat is that the selection has to be a scalar, hence why you can't use `p.cars`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify `cars` as a field in your query.

Try adding `LEFT JOIN FETCH` clause, Person entity with associated collection that is joined will be loaded in single query:

```
SELECT p.name FROM Person p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.cars ORDER BY p.registration DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem of only wanting to fetch specific columns as part of the result-set payload.

Comment: And the result of your edit only returns the name, not the name ~and~ the collection of cars like they want.

Comment: Nope, I've already tried it. In a nutshell `LEFT JOIN FETCH` avoids the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` specified at compile time and force the load of the cars.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't support doing what you're asking, at least not through the path you're trying to take.  But if you approach the problem from the perspective of the `Car`, you can.

```
SELECT c, c.person.name FROM Car c ORDER BY c.person.registration DESC
```

If you'd like to stuff this result set into a value-object automatically, you can use the `SELECT NEW` syntax or you can  use the JPA `CriteriaBuilder#construct` method.

```
SELECT NEW MyValueObject( c, c.person.name )
FROM Car c 
ORDER BY c.person.registration DESC
```

You could then take the `List<MyValueObject>` in combination with Java Stream API and group the results like you want in memory, if that's necessary.

Just understand that the result set you get contains:

- A `Car` instance
- A `String` instance that contains the `Person`'s name value.

**UPDATE**

To build a map of associated `Car`, I'd likely probably add passing the `c.person.id` as another constructor argument to the `MyValueObject` in case you run into situations where you have two people with the same name.

```
List<MyValueObject> queryResults = query.getResultList();
List<List<MyValueObject>> groupedResults = queryResults
  .stream()
  .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( MyValueObject::getPersonId ) )
  .values();
```

Each entry in `groupedResults` is the list of `Car` instances associated to a given `Person` wrapped up as a `MyValueObject` instance.

Comment: i need to list person name with his/her cars as collection

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
session.createQuery("Select ps.name from Person as ps JOIN FETCH ps.cars ORDER BY ps.registration DESC");
```